# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 arises when building Xcode4.3.2 project

Tags: objective-c, mbprogresshud

the error above arises when i attempt to build an Xcode project , the details of the error appears below , i can't understand the reason of this error, or how to resolve it, please help, thanks.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BasicViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for the simulator as well.

Comment: what's MBProgressHUD?, and how to build it?

Comment: glad I was able to help guide you to the fix!